Правильно ли сказать Вон с России?
Правильно ли сказать ,,,Вон с России''?

Вон с России?

По грамматике это, конечно, неверно, а правильно: Вон из России!

Ведь Россия — это страна, государство, а не территория. Предлоги ИЗ и В используются, если предмет имеет организованную внутреннюю структуру: в Россию, из России.
В противном случае используют предлоги НА и С, например: приехать с Урала, поехать на Урал, так как Урал — это природная эона, территория.

В то же время нестандартная  грамматика может использоваться в стилистических  целях, например для усиления значения: с территории России. Или еще выразительнее: с российской земли.

